# How to read flt files in python

Tags: python

In Python, I want to read a .flt file. Is there any library support to read bathymetry data? FLT files create 3D geometry models for real-time simulations. This file type is the most-used 3D format within the global visual simulation sector.

Kindly advise.

Input File format:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more information on your specific use case. I'm not super familiar with flt files but I know python has an flt library that can be installed with pip install flt. I can recommend more libraries based on your specific use case.

Comment: @imad97 I need to read .flt (extension file). Bathymetry is the study of underwater depth of lake or ocean floors. Bathymetric charts are typically produced to support safety of surface or subsurface navigation, and usually show seafloor relief or terrain as contour lines and selected depths, and typically also provide surface
navigational information. This data input has .flt extenstion

Comment: @imad97 hi any library support to read .flt file in python